# in MOD_Rewrite / ISAPI_Rewrite, how do I make rules affect specific domains?

Tags: mod-rewrite, isapi-rewrite, clean-urls

I just recently migrated from a linux host to a dedicated server with windows 2003, I had only one site using Mod_rewrite, but with ISAPI _Rewrite 3 free, the rules are global.

How do I write a condition to affect only "mysite.com" and not the others?

this is my httpd.conf file

```
# Helicon ISAPI_Rewrite configuration file
# Version 3.1.0.66

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

I dont want to buy ISAPI_Rewrite just for this one site

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least concerning [Apache’s mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html), you could use the [`C` flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags) to chain the rules like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =example.com
RewriteRule ^ - [C]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1 [C]
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/?$ index.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L]
```

If one rule does *not* match, all following chained rules are skipped. That means, if the first rule does not match (host name is not `example.com`), the following chained rules are skipped. Note not to add the `C` flag to the last rule as the chain flag.

Comment: what's "RewriteRule ^ - [C]" for? I tried it didnt work but I think it has something to do with "RewrieBase /" or HTTP_HOST is not working somehow, thanks for answering btw

Comment: @zombiegx: I explained that in my answer: “[…] if the first rule does not match (host name is not `example.com`) […]”